# Is it possible to add an attachment element without the surrounding HTML tags to Trix editor

Tags: trix

Im trying to add an  element to my trix editor with specific classes. As far as im aware this can only be done using the attachment like so:

```
var attachment = new Trix.Attachment({ content: '<a class="class1 class2">@trix</a>' })
element.editor.insertAttachment(attachment)
```

The issue with this though is that `Trix.attachment` surrounds the element im adding with a `<figure>` element and inserts a fig caption element (so having to write a script that removes these and it just seems messy)

And when i try use the `insertHTML` function is removes any class i set on the HTML element im inserting.

So i guess im asking is there a way to use `insertHTML` without it removing classes i set on the elements or is there a way i can insert an attachment without it surrounded with extra HTML

Thanks